# Difference between "acquire" and "own"?

Tags: meaning

I read an [article](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-have-and-vs-get/) about the difference between *get* and *have*. There is a explanation:

> This is a major difference between the two verbs ‘have’ and ‘get’. The verb ‘get’ gives the meaning of ‘acquire’ as in the sentence ‘I want to get it now’. The sentence actually means ‘I want to acquire it now’. On the other hand the verb ‘have’ gives the meaning of ‘own’ as in the sentence ‘I want to have it right now’. The sentence actually means ‘I want to own it right now’.

However, I don't still understand it because I don't know the difference between two sentences: "I want to acquire it now" and "I want to own it right now".

What's the difference between the two sentences?

---

sorry! I supposed that my question might be unclear. 
I know the meaning of the word acquire and own and the difference, definitely.
But I don't know the difference 'want to acquire' and 'want to own'
If you were a native speaker, you might not understand 
how I can't understand the difference between 'want to acquire' and 'want to own' although I know the difference between acquire and own. But in my first language, there is no difference between 'want to acquire' and 'want to own(or have)'. That's the reason I have a trouble to get it.

Comment: What research have you done? Did you look up *acquire* and *own* in a dictionary?

Comment: I acquired a car last night. Trouble is I don't own it, and now the cops are on my tail.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, the verb 'acquire' represents an action - that of obtaining - and the verb 'own' represents a state - that of possession.

'I want to acquire it now' focuses on the immediate impulse to obtain the desired object, be that by grabbing, stealing, or buying.

'I want to own it now' focuses on the desired state of possessing the object after it has been obtained, with no focus on the act involved in acquiring, only the satisfaction of possession.

Comment: Right. _Acquire_ is active, _own_ is stative. _Acquire_ can be used in the imperative and the progressive, both of which require an active predicate: _Acquire that company immediately! She is gradually acquiring all the mineral rights in the area._ These would be ungrammatical with _own_. That's the biggest difference.

Answer (score 2):

To acquire something - *To achieve or get something*

To own something - *To possess or have something*

Lets get it further cleared up with the help of an example.

> I want to acquire programming skills

The above sentence depicts the desire of the person to learn or get programming skills.

> I want to have programming skills.

The above sentence depicts the desire of the person to *have* or *own* programming skills.

So if we put them sequence, First we *acquire* a particular object or skill and then we *own* or *have* it.

> I want to acquire a driving licence. (And fter I get one, it becomes) I own a driving license

Comment: I understand your explanation fully. but can you give me some examples of object not skill.  like 'I want to acquire a house.'

Comment: @esllearner "I want to acquire a house" - Here I express my desire to get/purchase one. "I have a house" - Here I already possess a house *after acquiring* it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

*Owning* something, or *having* something means that it is in your possession.
*Acquiring* something, or *getting* something means that it is *not* in your possession yet, but you are in the process of transferring it to your possession.

> I will get some apples. => I do not have them yet, but I will go to the store and exchange some money in return for apples.
>
> I have some apples. => I am in possession of apples. Maybe I bought them, may be I grew them, maybe someone gave them to me.

In general, *having* something is the **result** of *getting* it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two phrases:

1. I want to **own** a dog.
2. I want to **acquire** a dog.

Although both phrases have the same end result (having a dog), they are putting their focus in different places. The first phrase focuses on the state of actually having the dog, while the second focuses on the method of getting the dog.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any situations you should say 'want to acquire' 
instead of 'want to own' or vice versa? Can you give me some examples.